# Nested Model Form p1 Railscasts example

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

Has anyone managed to make the example at http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1 work?

When I followed through the sample, it never saves any question nor the answer to the database but it manages to create a new survey entry.

I am using:

Rails 2.3.5 
ruby 1.8.6 (2008-08-11 patchlevel 287) [i386-mswin32]
nifty-generators (0.4.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes all the steps in the railscasts aren't accurate. It's better when you get the source code from the railscast, that are available and check the demo project.

Comment: no problem. I did the same than you. I hope this thread can help other users :-)